# String to unsigned long append the ascii value in binary. C++

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a way to simply append the ASCII value of text[i] to an unsigned long.

For an example:

string something = "abc";

The ASCII values are 97, 98, 99.

I'm **NOT** trying to get a sum of 97, 98, 99 making it 294 it should be **6 382 179**.

**EDIT**

For clarification: Meaning that the value that is appended it's the 8 bits of the ASCII values: 0b01100001 + 0b01100010 + 0b01100011 making it: 0b011000010110001001100011 = 6 382 179.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

unsigned long message(string text){
    unsigned long temp=0;
    for (int i = 0; i != text.size(); i++)
    {
        temp += int(text[i]);
    }
    return temp;
}

int main(){

    string something = "abc";

    cout << message(something);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I'm **NOT** trying to get a sum of 97, 98, 99 making it 294 it should be **6 513 251**" what does that mean?

Comment: My bad the value should be  6 382 179 -> from appending the 8bit value of ASCII

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the left shift operator to move the existing bits before you add the new bits

```
unsigned long temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i != text.size(); i++)
{
    temp <<= 8;
    temp += text[i];
}
return temp;
```